# How to direct all internet data transmission as torrent?

Tags: networking, router, bittorrent, protocol, transmission

I have 4 Mbps (which will be 500KBps) internet connection but it always gives torrent speed at 1.5 **MB**ps. So cool, right? So, is there any way I can make the ISP see my whole internet data transmission as like those torrent transmission. Even cooler is that the torrent data does not throttle my actual other 500KBps. Its like I have two separate data connection for torrent and others.

Comment: Maybe you get 1.5MBps not from the internet but from the LAN you are connected to? (e.g. your neighbours give you additional 1MBps)

Comment: How did you measure these values? Torrent and download manager software uses multiple connections (peer to peer or to server) to finish jobs faster.

Comment: Actually my plan is 10Mbps but after data limit it reduces to 4Mbps. The speed I am getting in the torrent is from that initial plan 10Mbps(1.5MBps). But the reduction somehow does not apply to torrents.

Comment: @Nikhil_CV I tested my internet connection speed with speedtest.net. And the torrent speed just shows up in the bittorrent app. The speedtest.net shows 10Mbps and 4Mbps after reduction. And yes, even IDM does not get past 500KBps. Its only the torrents that work its way through.

Comment: I think speedtest.net is giving you the most correct speed. The Torrenting speed may be wrongly calculated by the client. 1.5MBps is more than the normal speed ISP have allotted to you (1.25MBps)

Comment: @Nikhil_CV I don't know how to make you believe. Trust me its true. There's nothing mistaken about the speed. There's something wrong technically in their connection. It is like I said torrent runs separately limiting to 10Mbps however. But I still can download through regular ftp at 4Mbps simultaneously.

Comment: Then I'm out of opinion or suggestion on this atm. Sorry... :(